# Do I need to split order data into multiple time based index in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am planning to use Elasticsearch to store user orders data. There could be 20 million orders per year in my system. 20 million orders probably take about 10GB size.

My question is whether I should create one index to include all orders' data. I have read ES doc saying we'd better keep 20GB data in one primary shard. If I create one index with 5 primary shards, does it mean I am fine to save 100GB (200 millions) orders in this index?

Another approach is to create index per year, for example, I create index `order-2020`, `order-2021`, `order-2022` etc. And I can create less primary shard for each index. I understand using this pattern may benefit if I want to add a retention period on my order data. But apart from that, what other benefits I can have to use this pattern?

From query performance perspective, which approach is better?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of search speed and aggregation accuracy, multi-index multi-fragment will inevitably have some loss, but in terms of data health, it is recommended to split the data by year, you can use alias to establish index association, and the loss in query performance is much less than that in aggregation.